# How to make sure form's relative URL works?

Tags: html, forms

This is my webpage

```
www.domain.com/product/1
```

To update the product, I should submit to this URL

```
www.domain.com/product/1/update
```

In the product page, I have these forms to submit data

```
<form method="post" action="update">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="./update">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Both forms do not work, because it will submit to

```
www.domain.com/product/update
```

They only work if URL is

```
www.domain.com/product/1/
```

If I hard code the product id in action

```
<form method="post" action="1/update">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then `www.domain.com/product/1/` will not work, because it will submit to `www.domain.com/product/1/1/update`

What value should the action be to make sure the form can submit to correct URL?

If it is possible, I don't want to render absolute path or product id in form action.

Comment: There is something called "base" tag in html.  Maybe this can help: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp
Supply a base url  "www.domain.com/product/1" for that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands to ensure this works in all situations you will need to use the product ID, like so: `/product/1/update`.

Another option, though, would be to make a couple of tweaks server side to make sure directory URLs always have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you are asking for.

You have to specify either an absolute path or the product id.

You could generate the the product id programatically though.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble because the action path `product/1` is treated like a file not a directory, if the `1` had a slash after `domain.com/product/1/` then you wouldn't have any problems.  Like @sumitb.mdi suggested a base meta tag will work.

You're possibly using a framework, you might be able to utilise a URL builder function for 'named routes' or something.